# Insertar valores JSON en un tabla con PHP

Tags: php

Estoy intentando insertar valores de un Json a una tabla de mi base de datos CON PHP, esto es lo que tengo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]:

```
$json_pagina = file_get_contents('https://pagina');
$datos_json = var_dump(json_decode($json_pagina));
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$bd = "datqa";
$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass,$bd); 
    if (!$conexion) {
    die("Falló la conexión: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 echo "Conectado exitosamente";

foreach($datos_json as $json_data){ 
    mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO json_data (suggested_pickup,suggested_pickup_period,dewpoint_c,dewpoint_f,dewpoint_string,heat_index_c,heat_index_f,heat_index_string,location,latitude,longitude,observation_time ,observation_time_rfc822,pressure_in,pressure_mb,pressure_string,relative_humidity,station_id ,temp_c,temp_f,temperature_string,wind_degrees,wind_dir,wind_kt ,wind_mph ,windchill_c,windchill_f,windchill_string)
    VALUES (".$json_data['suggested_pickup']."','".$json_data['suggested_pickup_period']."','".$json_data['dewpoint_c']."','".$json_data['dewpoint_f']."','".$json_data['dewpoint_string']."','".$json_data['heat_index_c']."','".$json_data['heat_index_f']."','".$json_data['heat_index_string']."','".$json_data['location']."','".$json_data['latitude']."','".$json_data['longitude']."','".$json_data['observation_time']."','".$json_data['observation_time_rfc822']."','".$json_data['pressure_in']."','".$json_data['pressure_mb']."','".$json_data['pressure_string']."','".$json_data['relative_humidity']."','".$json_data['station_id']."','".$json_data['temp_c']."','".$json_data['temp_f']."','".$json_data['temperature_string']."','".$json_data['wind_degrees']."','".$json_data['wind_dir']."','".$json_data['wind_kt']."','".$json_data['wind_mph']."','".$json_data['windchill_c']."','".$json_data['windchill_f']."','".$json_data['windchill_string'].")");
}
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: intenta quitar el `var_dump` a la variable `$datos_json`

Comment: Si se lo quito me manda todos los parametros que quiero como error,  como la imagen que añadi al inicio.

! ) Warning: Illegal string offset 'campo' in C:\wamp64\www\peoject\index.php on line 43
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0032 365680 {main}( ) ...\index.php:0

Comment: puedes poner lo que te daba el `var_dump`? asi no podemos entender si el bucle foreach tiene datos correctos para iterar. Inicialmente se me ocurre que deberias poner `json_decode($json_pagina, true)` para devolver un array asociativo en lugar de objetos

Answer (score 0):

El `$datos_json` que tienes ahora no tiene ningún dato por eso te da error.
Intenta el siguiente

```
$datos_json = json_decode($json_pagina, true);
```

Y arriba del foreach para que notes que si ha llegado el dato

```
echo $datos_json["suggested_pickup"];
```

OJO: Si tienes otro detalle con esto, manda el nuevo error

Comment: Si me manda el echo con el dato que quiero, perfecto pero cuando lo meto dentro del forech ma marca error
foreach ($jsonarray as $json_data) {
  $suggested_pickup_period = $json_data['suggested_pickup_period'];
}

Comment: **Dentro del forech ya me marca  el listado de mi json**,
Pero aun me marca 2 errores,  pues en la estructura el json que tengo hay 2 niveles que tienen mas datos.

el error es : Notice: Array to string conversion in

Comment: Separa por línea, para que sepas desde cuál es el error, me suena a que todavía una parte es Array y no string, que lo puedas poner en un echo no lo hace string

Answer (score 0):

**RESUELTO**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "json";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("La conexión falló: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Conectado exitosamente  <br>";

$paje_json = json_decode($paje_json = file_get_contents("https://pagina"), true);

echo "MENSAJE: " .$paje_json['suggested_pickup'];
    foreach($paje_json as $key => $data) {
        echo "<p><b>$key</b> : $data </p>";

        if (is_array($data)) {
            foreach($data as $x => $z) {
                    echo "<p><b>$x</b>: $z</p>";
                }
            }
        } 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO demotabla (suggested_pickup,suggested_pickup_period,dewpoint_c,dewpoint_f,dewpoint_string,heat_index_c,heat_index_f,heat_index_string,location,latitude,longitude,observation_time ,observation_time_rfc822,pressure_in,pressure_mb,pressure_string,relative_humidity,station_id ,temp_c,temp_f,temperature_string,wind_degrees,wind_dir,wind_kt ,wind_mph ,windchill_c,windchill_f,windchill_string)
     VALUES ('".$paje_json['suggested_pickup']."','".$paje_json['suggested_pickup_period']."','".$paje_json['dewpoint_c']."','".$paje_json['dewpoint_f']."','".$paje_json['dewpoint_string']."','".$paje_json['heat_index_c']."','".$paje_json['heat_index_f']."','".$paje_json['heat_index_string']."','".$paje_json['location']."','".$paje_json['latitude']."','".$paje_json['longitude']."','".$paje_json['observation_time']."','".$paje_json['observation_time_rfc822']."','".$paje_json['pressure_in']."','".$paje_json['pressure_mb']."','".$paje_json['pressure_string']."','".$paje_json['relative_humidity']."','".$paje_json['station_id']."','".$paje_json['temp_c']."','".$paje_json['temp_f']."','".$paje_json['temperature_string']."','".$paje_json['wind_degrees']."','".$paje_json['wind_dir']."','".$paje_json['wind_kt']."','".$paje_json['wind_mph']."','".$paje_json['windchill_c']."','".$paje_json['windchill_f']."','".$paje_json['windchill_string']."')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
          echo "Nuevo registro creado exitosamente";
    } else {
          echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
```